# I have main_project/templates directory to store base.html, but where do I store base.css?

Tags: django

So, as I said I have a `base.html` file located at `main_project/templates/base.html`, but where do I put the `base.css` file? Do I create a `main_project/static` directory or should I just put in `main_project/templates`?

This seems like it should have a simple answer but I have only seen questions asking where to store base.html, and am unsure where to store base.css Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All static resources go in static folder examples are, CSS,js,logo images,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

You need to add above code to settings.py to configure static directory. Then you can create a folder called 'static' where your manage.py files are.
After that in urls.py you have this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And then you can use those files in the template using

```
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Note:- if have dynamic files that change for each page, example blog post images, they are stored in media folder. To know more you can read
Read Full documentation here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: this won't affect the static files I have in individual apps?

Comment: If you have static files in each app, then you have to use collectstatic command